# Import TypeScript namespaces (as in C#/.NET)

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces

In my TypeScript project I use classes and interfaces spread across several files structured in namespaces. Just as I use to do it in C#/.NET.

---

**IDispatcher.ts**:

```
namespace Dispatcher {
    export interface IDispatcher {
        Dispatch(msg: string): Promise<string>;
    }
}
```

**DispatcherImpl.ts**:

```
namespace Dispatcher {
    export class Dispatcher implements Dispatcher.IDispatcher {
        Dispatch(msg: string): Promise<string> {
            return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve('result');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.ts**:

```
namespace Test {
    export class Test {
        private dispatcher: Dispatcher.IDispatcher;

        constructor() {
            this.dispatcher = new Dispatcher.Dispatcher();
        }
    }
}

let testRun = new Test.Test();
```

---

Everything compiles fine to JavaScript (using `target` and `module` = `es6`).
But when I run `node test.js` I get the **error**

```
this.dispatcher = new Dispatcher.Dispatcher();
                      ^
ReferenceError: Dispatcher is not defined
```

When I try to `import DispatcherImpl` it states that `File 'DispatcherImpl.ts' is not a module`. And with `require('DispatcherImpl.ts')` it just resolves to `any` and does not work as expected either.

So I expect TypeScript namespaces to behave similar to .NET namespaces. But that does not seem to be the case at all.
How is the proper way to arrange my interfaces and classes and how do other classes use/import them? Maybe there is a way to make the TypeScript compiler resolve the namespaces automatically?

Comment: Actually looking to the future you shouldn't use namespaces any more. In ES6 each file is a module. Anyway how are you importing things? with `///reference`?

Comment: Tahnks for the hint. Actually there are no imports and no reference paths right now because the TSC works without any error.

Comment: It all depends on many things. I guess your problem is that the different files are not getting the right order when being compiled and then JS doesn't find things. Try to check the configuration in tsconfig.json

Comment: This topic has already been discussed in Github: [TypeScript#2159](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2159) (confusion for C# developers [_closed_]), [TypeScript#2956](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2956) (request for importing namespaces [_open_]). The latter is open since April 2015 so chances seem slim that a bare-import of namespaces is going to come (soon or at all).

Answer (score 0):

[Currently](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2956) there is no `include` oder `import` statement for namespaces in TypeScript.

I found a workaround using the `outFile` option in *tsconfig.json*:

```
"outFile": "test.js"
```

This way all TypeScript code gets translated into one single JavaScript-file.
To be arranged in the correct order every TypeScript file has to define its dependencies by e.g.

```
/// <reference path="DataModel/Common.ts" />
```